# react-slick carousel arrows not showing

Tags: next.js, carousel, styled-components

I am trying to implement the react-slick carousel in to my nextjs ecommerce website.
It is working ok except that the next/prev arrows are not showing.
Also there is a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the screen as if the component is too wide.

I am using styled components. I have tried changing width, padding, position etc but nothing seems to work.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for the Carousel component

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Slider from 'react-slick'
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css'
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css'

const Wrapper = styled.div``

const SliderImage = styled.img`
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px 2vw;
  object-fit: cover;
`

const Title = styled.p`
  display: flex;
`

const CarouselDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
`

export default function Carousel({ images }) {
  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 1000,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    arrows: true,
    classname: 'slides',
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {images.map(image => {
          return (
            <Wrapper key=''>
              <CarouselDiv>
                <SliderImage src={image.url} alt={image.alt} />
                <Title>{image.name}</Title>
              </CarouselDiv>
            </Wrapper>
          )
        })}
      </Slider>
    </div>
  )
}
```